# Xamarin Forms SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I want to save my data in SQLite data base so I installed the SQLite.Net-PLC nuget and I've created a connection in android and iOS, then I've installed the SQLite.Net.Async-PLC nuget and created a repository, where I define the functions: insert, update and delete like:

```
public Task<int> InsertAsync(T entity) {
        return _connection.InsertAsync(entity);
    }
```

Also I create tables like this:

```
 public Repository(ISQLiteConnection connectionService) {
        _connectionService = connectionService;
        _connection = _connectionService.GetConnection();
        _connection.CreateTableAsync<T>();
    }
```

In my page I want to insert an the table:

```
ISQLiteConnection connectionService = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteConnection>();
var activityRepo = new Repository<Activity>(connectionService);
await activityRepo.InsertAsync(activity);
```

It gives me this error :SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: no such table: Activity

I put a break point, it's creating the table and the error pop up on the insert async statment.

Comment: The table is being created async too. Did you try to await it ? Maybe the table isn't created yet.

Comment: I'm trying to put the create table in a separate function and then call the function with await but it gives me this error: System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[System.String]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did ignore the warning under this line of code:

```
_connection.CreateTableAsync<T>();
```

The warning would clearly state that this call is not awaited. So, the constructor of the `Repository` is likely to return before the table being even created.

```
var repo = new Repository(connectionService);
await repo.CreateTablesAsync();
```

And change your Repository:

```
public async Task CreateTablesAsync()
{
   await _connection.CreateTableAsync<T>();
}
```

Don't remove any of the above `await` keywords or you're gonna run that method and not wait for it to end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it gives me an error under Task<Void> and the function name because it should return

Comment: @Mireille Answer fixed. Please recheck

Comment: it gives me this error System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[System.String]

Comment: Okay I got it I have an observable collection in my Activity class, and SQLite doesn't support it

Comment: @Mireille you cannot store collections in your table ... can you show an example of what are trying to store ?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to use the SQLite-Net Extensions and use OneToMany